# How to instantiate prefab of player shield so it will look like player is in a bubble?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple game in Unity and I have added some power ups. One of the power ups is a player
shield which instantiates on the player position and then follows him around. This shield is just a sphere with a transparency material. My problem is that when i instantiate shield it doesn't look like player was in the shield like in a bubble but it look like it is behind the shield. Can anyone help me out here?

[Here Is the picture how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPkrl.png).

**I want it to look like he is in a bubble. Can anyone help me out here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, to me, it looks more like it is in front of the shield. Regardless, design-wise, there are four things that immediately come to mind:

1. Increase opacity of the bubble so that it clearly changes the color of the object inside of it
2. Give it an effect. Some sort of particle effect that sparkles or moves, therefore you will see it move across and behind the object within it
3. Ground it. have it hit the ground and result in a shadow. Shadows and a connection to the ground will provide a better perspective of where each item is
4. Give it a more reflective surface than the object inside it. Or change the dynamic so instead of the object reflecting light in the world, the shield does

This [image](https://www.google.com/search?q=game%20shield%20bubble&sxsrf=ALeKk024wpzzBs-DzuWEA-We371qafakcA:1589231712615&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSssi93azpAhUUOH0KHTkID1kQ_AUoAXoECA4QAw&biw=1536&bih=722&dpr=1.25#imgrc=NI4hq6CJF-qjRM) conceptually shows a bit of what I referring to. Also, when it comes to design ideas, reddit is an awesome place to get opinions. [r/Unity3d](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/) has a ton of helpful and friendly people that like to see people's ideas and are more than willing to comment on design. Rather than here, where it is much more programming oriented.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that did help me :D I changed materials shader mode from "Standard" to "Particles/Standard Surface" and set rendering mode to "fade" and now it works :)

Comment: @AdrianLorenčič Glad it helped! Feel free to share a pic if you'd like!